# Phpunit test a method that uses another class which is injected in the constructor

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Say in my class's constructor I inject another class. In one of my methods my return depends on that class. How can I test that return?

```
class MyClass {

    protected $directoryThatIWant;

    public function __construct(
        \AnotherClass $directoryThatIWant
    )
    {
        $this->directoryThatIWant = $directoryThatIWant;
    }

    public function getVarFolderPath()
    {
        return $this->directoryThatIWant->getPath('var');
    }
}
```

and my test class:

```
class MyClassTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    const PATH = 'my/path/that/I/want';

    protected $myClass;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $directoryThatIWantMock = $this->getMockBuilder(AnotherClass::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $this->myClass = new myClass(
            $directoryThatIWantMock
        );
    }

    public function testGetVarFolderPath()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(self::PATH, $this->myClass->getVarFolderPath());
    }
}
```

A method from a mock object returns null, so i'm unsure how I can ensure that `$this->myClass->getVarFolderPath()` returns the value that I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to define the behaviour of the mocked object (as described in the test double phpunit guide [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html)).

As example you can change the setup method as follow:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $directoryThatIWantMock = $this->getMockBuilder(AnotherClass::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $directoryThatIWantMock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getPath')->with('var')
        ->willReturn('my/path/that/I/want');


    $this->myClass = new myClass(
        $directoryThatIWantMock
    );
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks. I've seen examples with willReturn(...) but I am confused. That doesn't test anything right? I will not be sure that my method getVarFolderPath returns what I want

Comment: the mocked object constructed test that the method will be called only one time (with expect once) then you assert that your real class will use correctly the object and your asserting go fine. Do your test work fine now? or you got some error/wrong expection?

Comment: yes, it works like this, but here I don't really test the output of `$this->directoryThatIWant->getPath('var')`. I am doing this test because my hosting company often changes the absolute path to the var folder which leads to subtle errors. From my understanding, `willReturn()` just hardcodes in what you want, not? It doesn't really do what `\AnotherClass` does with the getPath method

Comment: Oh, sure, the class under test is MyClass and is an unit test. Probably you want to do a functional test with the real class involved and not mocking them